# how do I find supremum of the set

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

I have a test on Monday and the professor gave a hint about the problem.
f : ??? is random
How do I solve this problem?

> Let $f: [-10, 10] \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x) = ???$. Let
>   $\Delta$ be the set of positive numbers such that $$\Delta = \{\delta:
>  |x-y| < \delta \implies |f(x)-f(y)| < 1\}\text{.}$$ Find the supremum
>   of the set $\Delta$.

Comment: What do you mean that $f(x)$ is random? From what set of functions is it being drawn?

Comment: I've deleted my answer. I misinterpreted the question...Do you mean that $f$ is any function from $[-10,10]$ to $\mathbb{R}$? That's how I interpreted it. But I think you meant fix a function $f$ first.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO there is no specific answer to the general problem as it would need properties of the given $f$.

Try a couple of different functions, e.g. $f(x) = 42$, $f(x) = x + 3$, $f(x) = 3x^3-2$, $f(x) = (x-4)/(x+2)$, $f(x) = \sin(x)$, $f(x) = \int_3^x \lfloor \log(y) \rfloor^2 / \sqrt{y}\, dy$ or whatever to get an idea.